# use android mediacodec encode aac on galaxy s4 4.3

Tags: android, encode, android-mediacodec, aac

I use MediaCodec to encode aac stream and then mux to mp4, I test on most devices works properly , but on Galaxy S4 with 4.3, API level 18, the problem cames, below is the code:

```
 if (mHasAudioTrack) {
            mAudioCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
            MediaFormat audioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 44100, 2);
            audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
            audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO);
            audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 2);
            audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 128000);
            try {
                mAudioCodec.configure(audioFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(logTag, "configure audio codec err:"+e.getMessage()+"use no audio");
                mHasAudioTrack = false;
                mAudioCodec.release();
            }
        }
```

and the error log is:

```
> 11-16 11:40:51.006  20858-21098/com.youku.demorecord
> E/TDScreenVideoWriter﹕ Create media codec context. 11-16 11:40:51.126 
> 20858-21594/com.youku.demorecord W/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.aac.decoder]
> Failed to set standard component role 'audio_encoder.aac'. 11-16
> 11:40:51.126  20858-21594/com.youku.demorecord E/ACodec﹕
> [OMX.google.aac.decoder] configureCodec returning error -2147483648
> 11-16 11:40:51.126  20858-21594/com.youku.demorecord E/MediaCodec﹕
> Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError
> -2147483648) 11-16 11:40:51.126  20858-21098/com.youku.demorecord E/TDScreenVideoWriter﹕ configure audio codec err:nulluse no audio
```

Any parameters is wrong?
Is there any guys face same problem and can give me some tips? thanks very much.
btw:I don't want to compile third aac encoder library use ndk.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue, but on a Galaxy S7.